# sudo apt update throwing error in ubuntu 22.04

Tags: apt, 20.04, updates, 22.04, sudo

```
Err:9 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jammy Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 127.0.0.1 3128]
Hit:10 http://mirror-osd-holding.de.bosch.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease
Hit:11 http://mirror-osd-holding.de.bosch.com/osd jammy Release
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu jammy Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Hi, can you try this command and retry `sudo apt-get update -y`? `sudo add-apt-repository universe`

Comment: The repository http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu doesn't provide any software for your version of Ubuntu. Remove this repository from your sytem.

Comment: The first one (*using details from your pasted question*) shows no support for *jammy* or 22.04, for the others I'd check the URLs